# The option group is associated with a different VPC than the request

Tags: amazon-rds, boto3

I am using boto3 to restore a db snapshot to a new db instance, which is not created yet.

```
rds.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=temp_db_name,
        DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot_id
        )
```

and I got this error message:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) 
when calling the RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot operation: 
The option group myproject-mysql-5-6 is associated with a different 
VPC than the request.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

I do not know how to locate the option group in the first place.

I can work out the `VpcId` and `OptionGroupName` from the data returned from `describe_db_snapshots`.

Here is a documentation [related to the VPC setting](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html):

> When you assign an option group to a DB instance, the option group is
>   also linked to the supported platform the DB instance is on, either
>   VPC or EC2-Classic (non-VPC). If a DB instance is in a VPC, the option
>   group associated with the DB instance is linked to that VPC. This
>   means that you can't use the option group assigned to a DB instance if
>   you attempt to restore the instance into a different VPC or onto a
>   different platform. If you restore a DB instance into a different VPC
>   or onto a different platform, you must either assign the default
>   option group to the instance, assign an option group that is linked to
>   that VPC or platform, or create a new option group and assign it to
>   the DB instance. For persistent or permanent options, when restoring a
>   DB instance into a different VPC you must create a new option group
>   that includes the persistent or permanent option.

However I don't see how this can be applied to the `restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot` call.

**EDIT**

If I tried to restore the snapshot in aws console, this option is available to me:
[image]

How can I set these information via the `boto3` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can set it via the right `DBSubnetGroupName` value

```
        DBInstanceIdentifier=target_db_name,
        DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot_id,
        DBSubnetGroupName="mysql"
   )
```